# Thunderbolt devices, including the thunderbolt controller itself disappears on reboot

Tags: thunderbolt

Here's when it works, on cold boots.

[image: Here's when it works, on cold boots]

Here's when it's not working.

[image: Here's when it's not working]

I've got a Maple Ridge TB4 controller in this HP Z2 Mini G9. If I cold boot, devices show up in Linux, but if I reboot they're gone and the TB controller itself is also gone from lspci.

Boltctl says my system isn't compatible with "force power" so IDK what else to try.

Running Jammy with 6.5 oem kernel

Linux nick-HP-Z2-Mini-G9 6.5.0-1014-oem #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 19 11:03:48 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I wonder if it could possibly be related to this?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/thunderbolt/icm.c#L2445

I should mention that Windows 11 works (separate boot cycle, **NOT rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu!**). There are no issues there.

Comment: If you are rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu, there is a very high probability that Windows has not “released” the hardware during the reboot process. Windows generally does this under the guise of “faster rebooting”. This issue is seen most often with network devices, but can also be found with various hardware controllers.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  The mention of testing Windows is from a totally separate boot cycle. 
So: Power turned off, plug computer in, boot Ubuntu -- everything works.
Reboot Ubuntu -- now thunderbolt is gone.